# Bash script sort files and then dump into files

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I need to sort many files and then dump into many files in order of `1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv` and so on with each file of equal size.

The following pipe sorts and then dump into a single huge file

```
cat input_files | sort > one_huge_file
```

How do I dump into multiple files?

Comment: Note that you should be using `sort input_files > one_huge_file` or even `sort -o one_huge_file input_files` which has the additional (possible) benefit that `one_huge_file` could be one of the input files, though in this case, it probably wouldn't.  The `cat | sort` notation is a candidate for the UUOC award.

Comment: How do you define 'equal size'?  Same number of lines?  Do you know how many lines are in the source files?  How many output files do you need?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: good advise on keeping the one_huge_file.  equal size means same number of lines, each source line can contain different number of lines, I can do a count on each source file.  I want to have for example 10000 lines per output file.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: what's wrong with cat | sort notation, is there a better way?

Comment: @user121196 There is nothing wrong with `cat | sort` per se, but why to fork another process when `sort` can read the input file on it's own. You are only calling `cat` so that `sort` can read stream of data thru the `pipe`, isn't it?

Comment: One problem with `cat | sort` is that you make the kernel copy all the data from one process (`cat`) to another (`sort`) down a pipe, making the kernel do a lot of copying whereas `sort` is quite willing and able to read the files for itself.  There is nothing wrong with piping generated data to `sort`; it is not always wrong to pipe to `sort`.  But it is silly to pipe to `sort` when `sort` can read the files itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this useful tool:

```
$ man split
```